# Set no-repeat to backimage in Asp:Chart

Tags: asp.net, css, background-image, pie-chart, aspchart

I am using `asp:Chart` control. It's property `BackImage` works fine.
But I am getting 2 errors to set the background image.

1. Unable to set `no-repeat` property of `BackImage`.
2. How to pass URL of image in `BackImage` property

Answer (score 0):

```
chartid.chartarea[].backimage="url of your folder";
chartid.databind();
```